# how to deploy symfony on cpanel in public_html

Tags: php, symfony, cpanel, symfony-3.3, public-html

Am trying to run symfony on the Cpanel in the public_html. But when I access app_dev.php page it shows me 500 Internal Server error. I tried all method which are available on internet. I did same thing on the localhost but it is working on the localhost on the port 8000. But not working on the Cpanel. finding some solution[image]

Comment: Check the server error logs

Comment: @JimL this is the error log showing:- SoftException in Application.cpp:261: File "/home/trendsmy/public_html/web/app_dev.php" is writeable by group

Comment: http://www.zyxware.com/articles/5012/solved-internal-server-error-softexception-in-application-cpp-256-file-public-htmlindex-php-is-writeable-by-group

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you can't browse app_dev.php except localhost, for this you have to add your public IP in app_dev.php

[check app_dev.php line 13](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.3/web/app_dev.php)

clear cache and check permission for cache logs and session.if it's not solved your problem then
just check Symfony log file, this will tell everything you need....

and one more thing after placing your file in public_html your URL should be youdomain.com/web

if you want to remove web from your url try this....

[shared hosting .htaccess for symfony](https://gist.github.com/habibun/15b5ca41c7f921108f6a)

Answer (score 0):

This is the permission problem. whenever you face this error please change the /username/public_html/web folder permission to 755 and app_dev.php -> 644 ,config.php -> 644 and app.php -> 644.